# Upload/handle file from Ajax request in Prototype js

Tags: magento, prototypejs, checkout

I am trying to handle the file from prototype.js Ajax request but its not working. Data is not getting in controller ($_FILES).

I have added one step in Checkout in magento and want to upload the file to go to next step.

I have also try with below code.

```
var request = new Ajax.Request(
                this.saveUrl,
                {
                    method: 'post',
                    requestHeaders: {"X-Prototype-Version": null},
                    contentType: 'multipart/form-data',
                    onComplete: this.onComplete,
                    onSuccess: this.onSave,
                    onFailure: checkout.ajaxFailure.bind(checkout),
                    postBody: formData,
                }
            );
```

Please help me here.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry to tell you but file uploads will not be that easy through ajax.

When posting through ajax the file input fields are either skipped or you only get the filename (instead of the file data).

There is a way to send the binary data though - but it takes a different approach.

Using the HTML5 File/FileReader API you can read the file in javascript and then put the contents of the file as the body of your request.

```
new Ajax.Request('/url.php?rawupload=1&id='+$F('id')+'&label='+label,
{
    'method':'post',
    'postBody':fileobject,
    'onSuccess':function() { alert('success'); }
});
```

You will need to put the form fields into the GET parameters so they get passed to your PHP script.

In your PHP script the file contents will be available like this

```
$file = file_get_contents('php://input');
```

`$file` will contain the contents of your uploaded file and you can write it to your file system or read the contents, etc.